# Getting error in Amazon Alexa

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

**Where I come from:**

I am making a skill for Alexa.
After uploading a .zip of my backend, I wanted to run a test.

**The problem:**

It prints this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'alexa-sdk'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:26:15)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have to get it to run `npm install`. Does your zip include the `package.json` file?

Comment: yes I have included it

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure when you create the zip file to upload to aws lambda that you are not 1 directory to high, You do not want to select one folder to zip. The directory that you zip should have a zip file that includes multiple folders i.e, node_modules, index.js, package.json and perhaps package-lock.json you should be selecting all individual folders separately then zip to create one zip file, if your a directory to high your path will be unclear to lambda function. Hope that helps.